# Initializing a member field with a member field of another class

Tags: c++, constants, member

I want to initialize a member field with a member field of another class.

```
// a.hpp
class A {
public:
    std::string m_protocol_field_end{"\n"}; // should be changeable, therefore no const
...

// b.hpp
class B {
public:
    const std::string m_protocol_field_end{A::m_protocol_field_end}; // should NOT be changeable, therefore const
```

I get this error:

```
error: invalid use of non-static data member 'A::m_protocol_field_end'
```

How to solve it?

Comment: so `B` also has a `const` `m_protocol_field_end` and you want it to be initialized from `A`'s  non-const `m_protocol_field_end`?

Comment: Do you want the fields as non-static members in every object, or do you want static members that are shared between all instances?

Comment: You specify that `A::m_protocol_field_end` is not `const`, rather it's mutable and can change. Then, it's not clear what you mean by `A::m_protocol_field_end` in `B`'s definition. Do you mean the default initializer's value? Do you mean the value some unnamed instance currently has? Are you assuming there is only ever one `A`?

Comment: You can't solve it. There's no such thing as `A::m_protocol_field_end`. `m_protocol_field_end` exists only in specific objects of type `A`. No object of type `A` - no `m_protocol_field_end`. Period. Which raises the obvious question: why is `m_protocol_field_end` non-static? Are you planning on having different `m_protocol_field_end` values in different objects of type `A`?

Comment: What if I make the first member field static outside of A? And then write const std::string m_protocol_field_end{m_protocol_field_end}; in B? Is the static free variable (in namespace X::Y::) then realy changeable?

Comment: One thing that might help explain what you are looking for is an explanation of what should happen when `A`'s field changes. Is that supposed to affect every `A` and `B` object that currently exists? Just those created in the future? Just `A` objects? Just a single `A` object?

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to take the value in the constructor so for example, if `class B`  is changed to this:

```
class B {
public:
    B(const string& protocol_field_end) : m_protocol_field_end(protocol_field_end) {}
    const std::string m_protocol_field_end;
};
```

This would let you do something more like this in code:

```
const A myA;
const B myB{ myA.m_protocol_field_end };
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I have an answer:

```
const std::string protocol_field_end_default{"\n"};

// a.hpp
class A {
public:
    std::string m_protocol_field_end{protocol_field_end_default}; // should be changeable, therefore no const
...

// b.hpp
class B {
public:
    const std::string m_protocol_field_end{protocol_field_end_default}; // should NOT be changeable, therefore const
```

OK now its not "single point of failure", but it works.

Comment: That works but only if it's the default/initial value you want to use. Seems like that's not the case here.

Comment: Now there are multiple constant strings with the same value: one as the global constant, and one in *each* object of type `B`. Seems like you would want to get rid of the field of `B`, or at least make it static within the class.